# Firefox plug-ins save into diffent folder Mac

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, firefox, plugins

I use **"Fire fox"** as my default browser. For last couple of days, I found my browser, running very slowly. As a step of speed it up, in a phase I wanted to delete all my **"Fire fox"** `Plug-ins`. In that time I found in internet that, the **"Fire fox"** `Plug-ins` should be stored in the "Hidden **"Library"** Folder" of Mac. But I didn't find any thing there. Then I kept searching for the `Plug-ins` & now I find that, they are stored in the "Unhidden or regular **"Library"** Folder". I am going to attach two screen shots so that you can understand the situation. Now My question is:

- Why the path is changed?
- Is it necessary to make it correct?
- If though, how could I do it?

If any one familiar with the question please reply me back. Thanks in advance. Have a good day.

It should be like this:

[image]

But I found it like this:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The `/Library/Internet Plug-Ins` folder contains plugins that can be used by any browser run from any account on your Mac. The `/Users/reashedzamil/Library/Internet Plug-Ins` folder contains plugins that can be used by any browser but only when it is run by you.

However a better way to check which plugins are actually being used by Firefox is to type `about:plugins` into the address bar in Firefox. It will list all the plugins loaded into Firefox and tell you where they are. You can also visit http://www.mozilla.org/plugincheck/ which will analyse your browser plugins and tell you which ones are out of date.

You will also find another folder called something like `/Users/reashedzamil/Library/Application Support/Firefox/Profiles/RANDOMTEXT.default/extensions` that contains plugins (also known as Extensions or Add-Ons) that will be run within Firefox only when it is run by you. However if you think that extensions are the cause of performance issues, the best way to remove them is to open Tools -> Add-Ons from the menubar and uninstall them from there.

Another thing you can use to check for performance problems in Firefox is to type `about:healthreport` into the address bar.

Comment: Sorry for late reply & Thanks for your very informative answer. Yes, I already check all of it. But, I was wondering could the performance going bad, If I bookmarked some infected sites? Because this is the only section leave, I didn't check.

Comment: When you bookmark a website all Firefox should do is load (and I'd assume cache) the favicon for the site. I'd think it very unlikely that bookmarking an infected site could have any affect on performance.

Comment: Yes, I also think so. I try almost all possible checking to detect the reason of delaying. Such as Delete Plug-ins & Extensions from both of the Library Folders, Clear Caches & Cookies, Checking Health Report, Reset Firefox, Terminal Command to check Malware attack possibility etc. But unfortunately no luck. I was searched a lot about the solution, but Firefox official forum is so much gnarled & boring. So, I came here. But now I am facing that the performance is little bit better, after installing a completely fresh Latest version of Firefox. Though don't know how long it will stay like that.

Answer (score 1):

Since your problem is not finding the extensions/plugins/addons files location on your hard drive but the **slow** Firefox, I would recommend:

To Reset Firefox do the following:

```
Go to Firefox > Help > Troubleshooting Information.
Click the "Reset Firefox" button.
Firefox will close and reset. After Firefox is done, it will show a window with the information that is imported. Click Finish.
Firefox will open with all factory defaults applied.
```

Alternatively to do some investigation:

Open Firefox HEALTH report (under help tab)

It shows vital information like:

- the start up times (it should be <2 seconds)
- Active/Not active Add-ons and Plugins: that would help you decide what to activate or not, rather than randomly deleting the files in your library.

Comment: Sorry for late reply. Thanks for your comment. Actually I did reset Firefox several times. After resetting, It behaved nice, but after some times, when install all Plug-ins & others, It again gonna slow. Last day, I downloaded a fresh Latest version of Firefox & currently using it. Delete all Plug-ins and others Mozilla stuff from Library folder. Now, It seems like the performance going a little bit better.<br/>
And about health report, The average Start up times is above 2 seconds. :(